# Querying Opportunities from Contact Records

Tags: soql, opportunity, contact

I am querying all the opportunities from a map of Contacts this way:

```
Map<Id, Contact> chosenContIdsMap = new Map<Id, Contact>(chosenConts); 
List<Contact> myCons= [SELECT Id, (SELECT Opportunity.Name From OpportunityContactRoles) 
                            FROM Contact WHERE Id =: chosenContIdsMap.keySet()];
```

How to separate Opportunities from the above `myCons` list and make them a separate individual list?

Comment: I don't know why I got a down-vote here. Whoever down-voted care to explain why?

Comment: Maybe because your question is a bit on the short side, and thus doesn't show a research effort? Not sure. Anyway, here, have my upvote to offset that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to loop through the results and add them to a list:

```
Opportunity[] oppRecords = new Opportunity[0];
for(Contact conRecord: myCons) {
  for(OpportunityContactRole oppConRole: conRecord.OpportunityContactRoles) {
    oppRecords.add(oppConRole.Opportunity);
  }
}
```